# How do i make post request through google-auth-library?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am successfully able to make GET requests to a service hosted behind IAP, but am running into issues when making POST requests the same way. Also, I was not able to find any documentation for the same. All examples seem to be for GET requests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Equally frustrated with the terrible documentation on that library. Here is how to make a POST:

```js
const { status, data } = await client.request({
    url: 'https://example.com/some/path',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        hello: 'world'
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks @nicolas - had to resort to reading the source code, this saved me a lot time for something so simple.

Comment: Agreed! Extremely frustrated that this is not very well documented!